# Tomcat refusing connection when trying to deploy from eclipse using maven

Tags: tomcat, maven

Why is Tomcat refusing connection  when trying to deploy from eclipse using maven?

How can this be fixed?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jj.cd</groupId>
  <artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dashboard Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>dashboard</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <server>mytomcat</server>
        <url>http://localhost:8686/manager/html</url>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Maven settings.xml

```
 <settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <activeProfiles>        
        <activeProfile>dev-build</activeProfile>        
    </activeProfiles>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>mytomcat</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>test</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
 </settings>
```

Entry in tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="test" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: What does the port configuration for the HTTP connector look like in Tomcat's server.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "/html" portion of the configured Tomcat manager URL:

```
    <url>http://localhost:8686/manager</url>
```

Comment: yes i changed as u said .but no hope.and the port number is correct .i can access the tomcat manager using  username and password .any idea ...

Comment: @Irene What is Maven's output when running in verbose mode? Add -e -X to your Maven command line.

Comment: C:\NEW_ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE\dashboard>mvn tomcat:redeploy                        INFO] [war:war {execution: default-war}]
INFO] Packaging webapp
INFO] Assembling webapp[dashboard] in [C:\NEW_ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE\dashboard\target\dashboard]
INFO] Processing war project
INFO] Copying webapp resources[C:\NEW_ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE\dashboard\src\main\webapp]
INFO] Webapp assembled in[51 msecs]
INFO] Building war: C:\NEW_ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE\dashboard\target\dashboard.war
INFO] [tomcat:redeploy {execution: default-cli}]
INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8686/dashboard
ERROR] BUILD ERROR

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow.i dont know how to add more comments .if u want entire maven output.will post it as a new question.

Comment: thank you so much for u r answer..finally i resolved it.i changed port number to 8080.then it started working.then again changed to another port number it .and it was working on that port number also.so tried with my old port number it ,it is working this time!!!!.i think i did some mistakes .will try to reproduce the situation to check what caused the problem.thank you

Answer (score 0):

With more recent tomcat versions the manager role has been split into more fine grained ones. Try again with your user having the manager-gui role?